# Extending prototypes in Javascript - good way?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype, extend

I want to validate that the approach I'm using is correct when it comes to extend a prototype - supposing "extend" is the right word.

This topic gets a lot of clones. I'm still trying to properly understand this topic...

The purpose is:

- to write clean and good code.
- to avoid using frameworks, if possible plain JavaScript.
- get advice on the clean frameworks that don't twist JS to obtain class-enabled behaviors.

Here is the Parent prototype of my sandbox:

```
function Parent(){

}

Parent.prototype = {

    "init":function(){

        this.name = "anon";
    },
    
    "initWithParameters":function(parameters){
    
        this.name = parameters.name ? parameters.name : "anon";
    },

    "talk": function(){
    
        console.log('Parent is: ' + this.name);
    }
}
```

Now the Child prototype - it adds a "position" property and redefines the behaviors:

```
function Child(){

    Parent.call(this);
}


Child.prototype = new Parent;
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.init = function(){

    Parent.prototype.call(this);

    this.setPosition(0, 0);
}

Child.prototype.initWithParameters = function(parameters){

    Parent.prototype.initWithParameters.call(this, parameters);

    if(!this.position){
        
        this.position = {x:0, y:0};
    }
    
    this.setPosition(parameters.pos.x, parameters.pos.y);
}
    
Child.prototype.setPosition = function(x, y){
    
    this.position.x = x;
    this.position.y = y;
}

Child.prototype.talk = function(){
    
    console.log('Child is: ' + this.name + ' and location is: ' + this.position.x + ', ' + this.position.y);
}
```

Is this a good practice? Is there no shorthand to avoid writing "Child.prototype." when overriding a property (using a literal maybe, like the Parent prototype is written).

I know of J. Resig's Class/extend approach. But I'd rather use JavaScript as the prototypical language it is, not make it work as a "class-like behaving class-less OO language".

Comment: `Child.prototype = new Parent;` is wrong.  http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Hi @SLaks, thanks for your input. I thought next line was correcting that:
"Child.prototype.constructor = Child;"
Doesn't it? When I read your article (nice read btw), I trust I had already taken that into account. Or am I missing some bigger picture?

Comment: No; what if `Parent()` has logic?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general your approach will work but a better approach will be to replace:

```
Child.prototype = new Parent;
```

with:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

This way you don't need to call `new Parent`, which is somewhat an anti-pattern. You could also define new properties directly as follows:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
  setPosition: {
    value: function() {
      //... etc
    },
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

[Object.create() at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: Interresting, I knew about the first parameter of the create function but not how to handle the second one. Will definitely look into that.

Comment: inb4 @Tobiq just ran this part, without `Parent` in scope.

Comment: Given your opinion of this usage of `new` being an anti-pattern, which I'd say is a popular view; are there *any* use cases where you find using `new` to be valid?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach it is a good pure JavaScript approach. The only get away from tipping "Child.prototype" every time is to put it in a reference variable.

Like:

```
  var children = Child.prototype;
  children.init = function(){ /*/someoverridecode*/}
```

But you are still doing the Child.prototype behind this. You can also define a function that does this for you, see bind of underscore, maybe it suits your needs.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Indeed, underscore.js contains some neat stuff!

Answer (score 3):

I may get deep fried for this suggestion as there are several articles that can argue against some practices in my example, but this has worked for me and works well for clean looking code, stays consistent, minifies well, operates in strict mode, and stays compatible with IE8.

I also like utilizing the prototype methodology (rather than all of the 'extend' or 'apply' styles you see everywhere).

I write out my classes like this. Yes, it looks a lot like an OOP language which you didn't want, but it still adheres to the prototypical model while holding similarities to other familiar languages which makes projects easier to navigate.

This is my style I prefer :) I'm not saying it's the best, but it's so easy to read.

```
(function(ns) {

  var Class = ns.ClassName = function() {

  };

  Class.prototype = new baseClass();
  Class.constructor = Class;
  var _public = Class.prototype;
  var _private = _public._ = {};

  Class.aClassProperty = "aValue";

  Class.aClassMethod = function(params) {

  }

  _public.aMethod = function(params) {
      _private.myMethod.call(this, "aParam");
      Class.aClassMethod("aParam");
  }

  _private.myMethod = function(params) {

  }

})({});
```

EDIT:

I went ahead and converted your example this style just to show you what it would look like:

```
var namespace = {};

(function(ns) {

    var Class = ns.Parent = function() {

    };

    var _public = Class.prototype;
    var _private = _public._ = {};

    _public.init = function() {
        this.name = "anon";
    }

    _public.initWithParameters = function(parameters) {
        this.name = parameters.name ? parameters.name : "anon";
    }

    _public.talk = function() {
        console.log('Parent is: ' + this.name);
    }

})(namespace);

(function(ns) {

    var Class = ns.Child = function() {
        this.position = {x:0, y:0};
    };

    Class.prototype = new ns.Parent();
    Class.constructor = Class;
    var _public = Class.prototype;
    var _private = _public._ = {};

    _public.init = function() {
        _public.init.call(this);
        this.setPosition(0, 0);
    }

    _public.initWithParameters = function(parameters) {
        _public.initWithParameters.call(this, parameters);
        this.setPosition(parameters.pos.x, parameters.pos.y);
    }

    _public.setPosition = function(x, y) {
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
    }

    _public.talk = function() {
        console.log('Child is: ' + this.name + ' and location is: ' + this.position.x + ', ' + this.position.y);
    }

})(namespace);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your work on this. Looks efficient indeed - Class oriented though ;-) It looks qui similar to Base.js (or jQuery) 's Class approach. Good code though!

Answer (score 1):

Coming from google in 2019.

From the [latest MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), the way to extend prototype is :

```js
function MyClass() {
  SuperClass.call(this);
}

// inherit one class
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);
// mixin another
Object.assign(MyClass.prototype, {
  //... your own prototype ...
});

// re-assign constructor
MyClass.prototype.constructor = MyClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally do it like this. I use the `class` operator now, but there's still a good way to do it in ES3.

## Using Node.js utilities

Node.js includes a [utility function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) for *this very thing*.

```js
const { inherits } = require('util');

function SuperClass () {
  this.fromSuperClass = 1;
}

function ExtendingClass () {
  this.fromExtendingClass = 1;
}

inherits(ExtendingClass, SuperClass);

const extending = new ExtendingClass();
this.fromSuperClass; // -> 1
this.fromExtendingClass; // -> 1
```

The above has [it's fair share of problems](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4179). It doesn't establish the prototypical chain, so it's considered *semantically incompatible* with the `class` operator.

### Using the `Object.create` API

Otherwise, you can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for this.

```js
function Person () {
  this.person = true;
}

function CoolPerson () {
  Person.call(this);
  this.cool = true;
}

CoolPerson.prototype = Object.create(Person);
CoolPerson.prototype.constructor = CoolPerson;
```

### Using a "helper function"

Please note that in the above example that uses the `Object.create` API, if you do not call `Person` (the "super class") in the `CoolPerson` (the extending class), instance properties (and optionally initialization) will not be applied when instantiating `Person`.

If you want to be more "elegant", you could even create a helper function for this, which might be easier for you.

```js
function extend(BaseClassFactory, SuperClass) {
  const BaseClass = BaseClassFactory(SuperClass.prototype, SuperClass);
  BaseClass.prototype = Object.assign(BaseClass.prototype, Object.create(SuperClass));
  BaseClass.prototype.constructor = BaseClass;
  return BaseClass;
}

function SuperClass() {
  this.superClass = true;
}

SuperClass.prototype.method = function() {
  return 'one';
}

const ExtendingClass = extend((Super, SuperCtor) => {
  function ExtendingClass () {
    SuperCtor.call(this);
    this.extending = true;
  }
  
  // Example of calling a super method:
  ExtendingClass.prototype.method = function () {
    return Super.method.call(this) + ' two'; // one two
  }

  return ExtendingClass;
}, SuperClass);

const extending = new ExtendingClass();
extending.method(); // => one two
```

### Using ES6's `class` operator

There's a new `class` operator in JavaScript that's been released in JavaScript that may make this whole experience more expressive.

```js
class SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    this.superClass = true;
  }

  method() {
    return 'one';
  }
}

class ExtendingClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.extending = true;
  }

  method() {
    // In this context, `super.method` refers to a bound version of `SuperClass.method`, which can be called like a normal method.
    return `${super.method()} two`;
  }
}

const extending = new ExtendingClass();
extending.method(); // => one two
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways I usually do it:

**Using a helper function:**

```
/**
 * A clone of the Node.js util.inherits() function. This will require
 * browser support for the ES5 Object.create() method.
 *
 * @param {Function} ctor
 *   The child constructor.
 * @param {Function} superCtor
 *   The parent constructor.
 */

function inherits (ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false
    }
  });
};
```

Then you might simply do:

```
function ChildClass() {
    inherits(this, ParentClass);
    // If you want to call parent's constructor:
    this.super_.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

**Extending prototype using Lodash**

```
_.assign(ChildClass.prototype, {
  value: key
});
```

**Or just give ES6 a chance!**

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor() {
        var date = new Date();
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        this.initializeTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentsClass {
  constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(this.initializeTime);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My example shows several things : Private variable, same parsing argument for the parant and child constructor, rewrite .toString() function try : `""+this`. :)

## full example with doc :

[image]

Output :

### Constructor arguments

```
MM = new Parent("val of arg1", "val of arg2");
Child1 = new childInterface("1", "2");
Child2 = new child2Interface("a", "b");

console.log(MM + "args:", MM.arg1, MM.arg2);
// Parentargs: val of arg1 val of arg2
console.log(Child1 + "args:", Child1.arg1, Child1.arg2);
// childInterfaceargs: 1 2
console.log(Child2 + "args:", Child2.arg1, Child2.arg2);
// child2Interfaceargs: a b
```

### Extend function in child class

```
MM.init();
// Parent: default ouput
Child1.init();
// childInterface: new output
Child2.init();
// child2Interface: default ouput
```

## Increment variable

```
MM.increment();
// Parent: increment 1
Child1.increment();
// childInterface: increment 1
Child2.increment();
// child2Interface: increment 1
Child2.increment();
// child2Interface: increment 2
MM.increment();
// Parent: increment 2
console.log("p", "c1", "c2");
// p c1 c2
console.log(MM.value, " " + Child1.value, " " + Child2.value);
// 2  1  2
```

### Private variable

```
MM.getHidden();
// Parent: hidden (private var) is true
MM.setHidden(false);
// Parent: hidden (private var) set to false
Child2.getHidden();
// child2Interface: hidden (private var) is true
MM.setHidden(true);
// Parent: hidden (private var) set to true


Child2.setHidden(false);
// child2Interface: hidden (private var) set to false
MM.getHidden();
// Parent: hidden (private var) is true
Child1.getHidden();
// childInterface: hidden (private var) is true
Child2.getHidden();
// child2Interface: hidden (private var) is false
```

### Protected variable

```
function Parent() {
  //...
  Object.defineProperty(this, "_id", { value: 312 });
};

console.log(MM._id); // 312
MM._id = "lol";
console.log(MM._id); // 312
```

```js
/**
 * Class interface for Parent
 *
 * @class
 */
function Parent() {
  this.parseArguments(...arguments);

  /**
   * hidden variable
   *
   * @type    {Boolean}
   * @private
   */
  var hidden = true;


  /**
   * Get hidden
   */
  this.getHidden = () => {
    console.log(this + ": hidden (private var) is", hidden);
  }


  /**
   * Set hidden
   *
   * @param {Boolean} state New value of hidden
   */
  this.setHidden = (state) => {
    console.log(this + ": hidden (private var) set to", !!state);
    hidden = state;
  }

  Object.defineProperty(this, "_id", { value: "312" });
}

Object.defineProperty(Parent.prototype, "nameString", { value: "Parent" });


/**
 * Parse arguments
 */
Parent.prototype.parseArguments = function(arg1, arg2) {
  this.arg1 = arg1;
  this.arg2 = arg2;
};


/**
 * Get className with `class.toString()`
 */
Parent.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.nameString;
};


/**
 * Initialize middleware
 */
Parent.prototype.init = function() {
  console.log(this + ": default ouput");
};


/**
 * Increment value
 */
Parent.prototype.increment = function() {
  this.value = (this.value) ? this.value + 1 : 1;
  console.log(this + ": increment", this.value);
};

/**
 * Class interface for Child
 *
 * @class
 */
function childInterface() {
  this.parseArguments(...arguments);
}


// extend
childInterface.prototype = new Parent();
Object.defineProperty(childInterface.prototype, "nameString", { value: "childInterface" });

/**
 * Initialize middleware (rewrite default)
 */
childInterface.prototype.init = function(chatClient) {
  console.log(this + ": new output");
};

/**
 * Class interface for Child2
 *
 * @class
 */
function child2Interface() {
  this.parseArguments(...arguments);
}


// extend
child2Interface.prototype = new Parent();
Object.defineProperty(child2Interface.prototype, "nameString", { value: "child2Interface" });

//---------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------

MM = new Parent("val of arg1", "val of arg2");
Child1 = new childInterface("1", "2");
Child2 = new child2Interface("a", "b");

console.log(MM + " args:", MM.arg1, MM.arg2);
console.log(Child1 + " args:", Child1.arg1, Child1.arg2);
console.log(Child2 + " args:", Child2.arg1, Child2.arg2);
console.log(" ");

MM.init();
Child1.init();
Child2.init();
console.log(" ");
MM.increment();
Child1.increment();
Child2.increment();
Child2.increment();
MM.increment();

console.log("p", "c1", "c2");
console.log(MM.value, " " + Child1.value, " " + Child2.value);
console.log(" ");

MM.getHidden();
MM.setHidden(false);
Child2.getHidden();
MM.setHidden(true);

console.log(" ");
Child2.setHidden(false);
MM.getHidden();
Child1.getHidden();
Child2.getHidden();

console.log(MM._id);
MM._id = "lol";
console.log(MM._id);
```